# Including sikuli to C# webdriver selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, sikuli

I've searched a lot, but I hadn't got the answer... Is it possible to include( attach, or something else) sikuli (using dll or something else, some code) into selenium webdriver test written on c# in visual studio 2010

Answer (score 5):

I use it like this:

```
internal bool FillSingleRow()
    {
        return RunTest("Stryktipset_singleRow.sikuli");
    }

public static bool RunTest(string sikuliTest)
    {
        var sikuliHome = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SIKULI_HOME");
        var execDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var tempDir = execDir.Parent;
            if (tempDir != null)
            {
                execDir = tempDir;
            }
        }

        Sikuli.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Sikuli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        Sikuli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        Sikuli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Sikuli.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = sikuliHome;
        Sikuli.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Sikuli.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar sikuli-script.jar -s " + '\u0022' + execDir.FullName + "\\Sikuli\\" + sikuliTest + '\u0022';
        Sikuli.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
        Sikuli.Start();

        var so = Sikuli.StandardOutput;
        var se = Sikuli.StandardError;
        var error = se.ReadToEnd();

        if (error != string.Empty)
        {
            TestLog.Write(error);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using [Sikuli from command line](http://sikuli.org/docx/faq/010-command-line.html)?

I don't know if Selenium has built-in support for running external tools, but in C# is pretty easy using a Process object to start another program and wait for its ending.

```
int exitCode;
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\pathto\sikuli.exe", "-parameters for command line");
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
exitCode = process.ExitCode;
process.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just got done putting together a java application that exposes the core functionality of Sikuli through a web service.  Then, by writing a "client" library that calls this java application, I was able to successfully call Sikuli from within a C# test with nearly full integration.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/sikuli4net/

Tons faster than running through command-line (that was my previous solution, and usually it tacked on about an extra 30 seconds to a test), and the client library automatically parses the response from the tool, so you don't need to do any string manipulation on the result!

Hope it helps -- I know it isn't an exact port of Sikuli, but hopefully it will get you what you need,

Answer (score 0):

So... This is the first way I figured out.

Use Blue Duck SDA:
http://sda.blueducktesting.com/index.php

That way you can execute whatever you want from Selenium (through AutoIT).

Next you are going to want a Pass / Fail output from Sikuli.  Use this wrapper:
http://code.google.com/p/simplesikuli/wiki/UsageDetails

You may or may not need to look at / use the full Robot Framework which that simplesikuli wrapper uses.  http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Sikuli4Net.sikuli_REST;
using Sikuli4Net.sikuli_JSON;
using Sikuli4Net.sikuli_UTIL;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        APILauncher launcher = new APILauncher();

        Pattern element1 = new Pattern(@"C:\myfolderforscreens\1.png");
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            launcher.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(8000);
            Screen test = new Screen();

            test.DoubleClick(element1);


        }
    }
}
```

Try this, should work.
p.s. You need install Json - version "6.0.5", set Java_Home and Sikuli_Home